# Syntax error in bash script: near unexpected token `else'

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

input=""

echo "Does a wall needs to be sent?"
read input

if [ $input="yes" ]; then
   echo "Sending message to all users"
   echo ""
else if [ $input="no"]; then
    exit
    fi
fi
echo "Is this a reboot or shutdown?"
      read input
if [ $input="reboot" ]; then
   reboot
elif [ $input="shutdown" ]; then
else
echo ""
echo "Goodbye"
```

Comment: Among other things, you need spaces around the assignments, eg., `[ $input = "yes" ]`...

Comment: elif dude, elif.  else is for the final catch-all.

Answer (score 4):

That script has a bunch of issues. Here's a cleaned up version:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=""

echo "Does a wall needs to be sent?"
read input

if [ "$input" = "yes" ]; then
    echo "Sending message to all users\n"
elif [ "$input" = "no" ]; then
    exit
fi

echo "Is this a reboot or shutdown?"
read input

if [ "$input" = "reboot" ]; then
    reboot
elif [ "$input" = "shutdown" ]; then
    shutdown -h now
fi

echo "\nGoodbye"
```

Honestly though, this is still really poorly done. I would recommend using `case` statements parsing arguments instead of reading input.